# Error on Lex Bot console - Reached second execution of fulfillment lambda on the same utterance

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I created a bot in Lex and then created two intents within same bot - `intent1` and `intent2` with utterance `get me a taxi now` and `I wan a taxi to {Location} on {TravelDate} at {TaxiTime}` respectively(first one in `intent1` and second one in `intent2`). Both the intents call different lambda function and inside lambda functions I access RDS to add the booking info for taxi. When I test from Lex console by saying either of the two utterances the lambda function executes completely as I can see database record updated but on Lex bot test console I see `Reached second execution of fulfillment lambda on  same utterance Lex error`. In my code I have this line:

```
def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }

def book_taxi(intent_request):

        confirmation_status = intent_request['currentIntent']['confirmationStatus']
#bunch of other processing code
        logger.debug('Confirmation = {}'.format(confirmation_status))
        if confirmation_status == 'Confirmed':

            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('confirmationContext'))
           logger.debug('confirmation_context = {}'.format(confirmation_context))
            if confirmation_context == 'AutoPopulate':
                    return elicit_slot(
                        session_attributes,
                        intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                        intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']

                    )
            return delegate(session_attributes, intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])
logger.debug('Booked Taxi at={}'.format(reservation))
```

My guess is that the `delegate()` call in code above is causing the issue because in my log files i can see the first two debug logs as Confirmed and None values but the last logger.debug() is not in the log file which means delegate() got called and thats is causing error on Lex console.

What could be the possible issue for this error?

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231264/3196845), might be of help

Answer (score 1):

Your Utterance May contains the text that invoke a more than one intent.
that's why the problem raised.
you chack the uttrances in both the intents and remove one from two similar type utterances.